# Can I apply for a US visit visa while an immigrant visa is in process?

Tags: visas, usa

I applied for my US immigration visa a year ago, and now I wish to visit my family in the US. The processing of my visa is going to take time. I was wondering if I could apply for a visit visa to meet them.

Answer (score 6):

Your chances of getting such a visa are very low.  The problem is your immigrant visa shows an intent to immigrate--and having an intent to immigrate is basically incompatible with being granted a tourist visa.